# Containerized jenkins : Cant find the /var/lib/jenkins folder

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins.

For the matter of testing, I have installed a containerized version on my machine (as described [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/))
The installation creates two containers. The one running the jenkins engine is jenkins-blueocean.

In non containerized version Jenkins saves its files in the /var/lib/jenkins folder but I cant find such folder in my containers:

```
docker container exec -it jenkins-blueocean /bin/sh
$ ls /var/lib/jenkins
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/jenkins': No such file or directory
```

Jenkins is running and I can see it both with ps and curl it on localhost:8080

So is the containerized jenkins saving files elsewhere or I am missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well I just checked.
Containerized Jenkins stores all files in /var/jenkins_home.

Cheers